# Convert PDF File to HTML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, webbrowser-control

I had a problem highlighting text in a pdf file embedded in webbrowser control and highlighting text using PDFLibNet.pdfwrapper so i'm shifting to another process where i'll just convert the pdf to html so i can manipulate the source code to highlight text. 

 How can i convert pdf files to html files? 
 Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Jepe

Comment: did you get any solution for this? Please help me I have same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the open source application [pdftohtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/). It should suit your needs, since you can use C# to automate the converting once you download this little console application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/programmers-guide.html) api to convert pdf to doc then onto HTML.